# Oracle:Check datatype of a variable

Tags: oracle10g

How can I check if the variable is a varchar/date/numeric datatype in oracle 10g procedure?
Like guess I have a variable in a procedure,that will be filled with various data(may be number,string or date).How to find this variable`s datatype in Oracle???

```
Declare
returnValue varchar2;

Begin
Text:=select col_name from tab_name where ID=:ID1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  Text into returnValue;
End;
```

Here 'ID1' will be sent dynamically."col_name" can have any data.
I have to check what kinda value is there in "returnValue" variable.?

Please suggest some answers.

Comment: have a look at the declaration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the datatype of a cursor or table column in a block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790148/finding-the-datatype-of-a-cursor-or-table-column-in-a-block)

Comment: You would want to create a variable in procedure? And these variables are defined or you would be dynamically creating it?

Comment: @StevieG:"Varchar2" datatype can have date value also right?

Comment: @Polppan:The variable which I have defined is of a type "Varchar2",but  i`m filling this with all kinds of data[Date,string].

Comment: @user1495475 Not at all a good idea to use vachar2 for Date data type. It would be better to post the procedure code rather than speculating.

Comment: @Polppan:Please check my post for the procedure.

Comment: @user1495475 I have updated my answer. See if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, bit its not particularly nice:

```
    declare
    v_date DATE;
    v_number NUMBER

    begin
        select to_date(variable_name,<date_format>) into v_date from dual;

    exception when others then 
        //its not a date
        begin
          select to_date(variable_name,<date_format>) into v_number from dual;
        exception when others then 
          //its not a number
          ...
          ...
        end;
    end;
```

Ideally, you shouldn't be putting multiple types of data into a single VARCHAR2 column - then you wouldn't have this problem in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `column_name` by

```
returnvalue tablename.columnname%TYPE;
```

So by this way the datatype of column will have the value stored in `returnvalue` variable

Update 1

```
returnValue tab_name.col_name%TYPE;

begin
select col_name into returnValue from tab_name where ID=:ID1;
return returnValue;
end;
```

Update 2

You could the following to get the data types from the following

```
select data_type || '(' || data_length || ')' col from user_tab_columns where
TABLE_NAME = '<YOURTABLE>'
```

Comment: Polppan:You mean to say "returnValue" will have datatype stored in it???If yes,what about the data I return to it?I want data also.And what is "tab_name.col_name%TYPE"?

Comment: @user1495475 `returnValue` will have the data from col_name, that's we use `into returnValue`

Comment: :Is "tab_name.col_name%TYPE" kind of datatype declaration?If yes that is not working,it`s throwing error like "returnValue: invalid identifier".

Comment: @user1495475 It is declaring a variable with the datatype of that column. Have a look at [this](http://www.example8.com/node/view/id/87752)

Comment: Polppan:Got it.But i`m sorry,table names,col name keeps on changing.